# Problem when stacking climatology variables from Chelsa with R

Tags: r

I have downloaded some climatological variables from Chelsa (e.g. bio1) for the years 1981 - 2010 and I wanted to assign it to a variable in R by using the stack() command from the raster library. The code I am using is pretty simple:

> bio1 <- stack("C:/Users/Tasos/wgetdown/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/climatologies/1981-2010/bio/CHELSA_bio1_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif")

I expected to get a Rasterstack object with 30 layers (one layer for each year from 1981 - 2010) BUT I am only getting a Rasterstack object with only ONE layer. I cannot understand why I face this issue. Can someone help?

Comment: I think you have downloaded the climatological mean values (climatologies) which means it is the average of all the years (1981-2010). So, it will be a single layer only.

Comment: I appreciate your help! So if I get it right, the correct files that I have to download are only those called "timeseries" ?